# Cause: zip END header not found after upgrading kotlin version to 1.9.10

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

I have a project which I can run with kotlin version 1.8.10 but when I change to version 1.9.10 I'm getting the following errors:
[Android Studio Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRcZ1.png)

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kspDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration11'.
   > Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar to match attributes {artifactType=classpath-entry-snapshot, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for ClasspathEntrySnapshotTransform: C:\Users\r1n1os\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.9.10\72812e8a368917ab5c0a5081b56915ffdfec93b7\kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar.
         > zip END header not found

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.10) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\r1n1os\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.9.10\72812e8a368917ab5c0a5081b56915ffdfec93b7\kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar.
         > zip END header not found

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.10) to match attributes {artifactType=android-jni, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for ExtractJniTransform: C:\Users\r1n1os\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.9.10\72812e8a368917ab5c0a5081b56915ffdfec93b7\kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar.
         > zip END header not found

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED in 16s
25 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 22 up-to-date
```

**What I have tried so far:**

1. I have tried delete the .gradle file
2. Download gradle files using this services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-bin.zip
3. Invalidate Cache

Do you have any idea what might be the issue?

**Below you can find my gradle files**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id ("kotlin-android")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.rockets"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.rockets"
        minSdk = 27
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.1"
}

var hiltVersion by extra("2.46.1")
var hiltCompilerVersion by extra( "1.0.0")
var retrofitVersion by extra("2.9.0")
val roomVersion by extra ("2.5.2")
val coroutines by extra("1.7.1")
val coroutinesLifecycle by extra("2.6.2")
val composeNavigation by extra ("2.7.3")

dependencies {
    //compose
    //implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$composeNavigation")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")

    //Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hiltVersion")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")

    //Network Manager
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion")
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion")

    //Local database Manager
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

    //Coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines")

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$coroutinesLifecycle")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$coroutinesLifecycle")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")

    //Glide
    implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:compose:1.0.0-alpha.5")

    // Test
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

---

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.10-1.0.13" apply false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the artifact was corrupted during download.

Try

1. Close Android Studio
2. Delete cached dependency jars: /.gradle/caches
3. Restart Studio
4. Re-open/sync project

If there are problems with locked files when trying to delete the gradle cached jars, kill any Java processes (some are likely gradle daemons) or restart your machine.

Comment: Thank you very match @ScottStanchfield that solve my issue!